# How do you install Owl Carousel?

Tags: jquery, css, installation, owl-carousel

I'm making a practice site and I've never made an image carousel before so I decided to try my luck at one. After some googling, I found Owl Carousel, which seems to be a pretty useful tool for making a carousel. However, I can't understand the instructions at all when it comes to installing it.

Here's what I have done so far:

1. I downloaded Owl Carousel and moved the 'assets' and 'owl-carousel' folders into my root directory.
2. I included all of this into my head tag:

   ```
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="flexbox.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css">
   <script src="assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
   ```
3. I setup my HTML like so:

   ```
   <div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
       <div class="img1"> Your Content </div>
       <div class="img2"> Your Content </div>
       <div class="img3"> Your Content </div>
   </div>
   ```
4. I added this to my CSS:

   ```
   #owl-demo .item img{
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   }
   ```
5. Lastly, I activated this script.

   ```
       <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {

       $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

           navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
           slideSpeed : 300,
           paginationSpeed : 400,
           singleItem:true

           // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
           // items : 1, 
           // itemsDesktop : false,
           // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
           // itemsTablet: false,
           // itemsMobile : false
       });
       </script>
   ```

I am trying to achieve this result:

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/one.html

Here is all of my code on Jfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/pd19q8vc/

This isn't at all how my website looks, but I just wanted the full amount of code to be available in case it is needed.

So what am I doing wrong? How can I get this carousel a'working?

Comment: you are missing the ) at the end (the "ready" call)

Comment: Whoops, nice catch. Unfortunately it still doesn't work after adding that.

Comment: your HTML markup needs to wrap in the #owl-demo ID

Comment: Hm, added it to the HTML but still no carousel.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        navigation : true, // Show next and prev buttons
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem:true

        // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
        // items : 1, 
        // itemsDesktop : false,
        // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
        // itemsTablet: false,
        // itemsMobile : false
    });
});
</script>
```

pleas add  }); before script tag closed

Answer (score 0):

please replace `owl-example` with `owl-demo` in div section where is `owl-example` and check. I hope it work.

Also you forgot to close the `ready function` at the end. add this `})` at the end.